# Is representation of float in python using base 10?

Tags: python, numbers, precision

I've read [this page](https://fr.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programmation_Python/Type#Les_nombres_.C3.A0_virgule_flottante_.28float.29) (french) on which we can read float type in python would use a base-10 representation, instead of the classical binary (as in Java for example).

It seems so weird to me I'd like to be sure. Is this really true ? Doesn't Python use IEEE 754 ?

Comment: If you need it Python does have a base-10 floating point type called [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, floats are represented with `PyFloatObject`s, which are just wrappers around `double`s:

```c
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    double ob_fval;
} PyFloatObject;
```

([source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Include/floatobject.h))

Comment: As an addendum, this can easily be tested in the interpreter.  Printing `'%.30f' % 0.1` would show 0.1 with trailing zeros, were the representation in base-10.  Since it shows a small difference from 0.1, the representation cannot be in base-10.

Comment: @EldritchCheese that's cool, i've tried ! Could you please explain the cmd ?

Comment: `%.30f` is a format string specifying that a floating point number will be given, and it should be printed with 30 values past the decimal point.  `%` is the format operator, with `0.1` as the number to be formatted.

Answer (score 1):

as arshajii said, cpython is using `double` for internal storage, but from

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-floatnumber -

> The allowed range of floating point literals is
>   implementation-dependent.

Representation you are reading about is how float are converted from and to strings (while compiler is parsing python source). How this number is internally stored is up to implementation.

Comment: Note that this refers just to *literals*, not floats themselves.

Comment: i am not sure that standards defines way floating point is defined. How floats are stored is implementation detail, not language detail, but I would be surprised if there is implementation that is using anything else that double for storage. It goes same for double. Double is type that is usually binary64 as per  IEEE 754 standard. In C++ standard for float/double/long double sais that it is implementation defined. (3.9.1.8 -> http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf)